# Filesystem files are counted and recognized as used space but dont show up

Tags: partitioning, mount, kubuntu, filesystem

I am running kubuntu 18.04.3.

I want to access files on one of my internal HDDs, recognized as `/dev/sdd`. It has 1 partition in `ext4` format. It gets mounted under `/media/$USER/1ed7ed5d-2874-4314-9931-404d8c34d838` (automatically). I can see and access it with the Dolphin File Manager without an error message, but files are not shown. It shows a blank directory. I can create files and folders there, and they persist after a remount. But my old files are still hidden.

An `ls -la` under `/media/$USER/1ed7ed5d-2874-4314-9931-404d8c34d838` also shows me an empty directory. Permissions are `777`, so they should not be the problem.

*However though*, KDE Partition Manager shows correct space used for that partition. Also, if I right click the directory in Dolphin, and select properties, it also shows up the correct space used and even the correct file count!

A `e2fsck -cfpv /dev/sdd1`, as recommended in topics I've found in the internet, gave no successful result.

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  1,8M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb2       480G  105G  351G  24% /
tmpfs           7,9G  282M  7,6G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop1       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop2      374M  374M     0 100% /snap/anbox/186
/dev/sdb1       511M  6,1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G   12K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2       466G   96G  370G  21% /media/$USER/769404BC50A5764D
/dev/loop3      311M  311M     0 100% /media/$USER/disk
/dev/sdd1       916G   89G  781G  11% /media/$USER/1ed7ed5d-2874-4314-9931-404d8c34d838
```

`getfacl /media/$USER` output:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/$USER/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:$USER:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Comment: can you show `df -h` please. Edit your question for output.

Comment: @nobody done that.

Comment: There are files on your filesystem.   Please test 2 things. `sudo apt install mc`  this is a cli filemanager. `mc  /media/$USER`  Use the arrow up and arrowdown keys to mark entries and enter to select. The second can you create a testuser, so we know if the error is in system or in your $HOME. `getfacl /media/$USER` please show these too.

Comment: @nobody `mc`-ing through the partition still just shows me the test files I created, not the hidden files. For `getfacl /media/$USER`, I've updated the question.

Comment: @nobody The testuser also dont show the files.

Comment: You could try `sudo du -h /media/` and see if any files get listed.